# How to find unique duplicates in SQL

Tags: oracle11g

Hi all i want to find the unique duplicate and their number of occurrence,

```
Table 1 
Id  name  Amount(in and out)  Day
1   ram   100                 Sunday
2   ram  -100                 Sunday
3   ram   100                 Monday
4   ram  -100                 Monday
5   ram   100                 Wednesday
6   ram   100                 Wednesday
```

Ram got 100 from the company on sunday i.e. id =1 and amount = 100 ,on same day he gave the money back to the Company i.e. id = 2,amount = -100

similay for id = 3 and id = 4

but id = 5 and 6 are duplicates as the amount is not reversed and it occured on same day .

i want to display

```
Count  name  Amount
2        ram  100
```

Count is the number of occurrence of duplicate values .

i have tried many logic but no use .please help me. thanks

Note : Duplicated means two sequential positive/negative values for the any day .

Comment: By day or globally?

Comment: Why do you want to display `100` if the outstanding amount is actually `200`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen answer is : amount 100 as occurred 2 times (count) for Ram

Comment: @McNets By globally means ?

Comment: all records, without partitioning by day

Comment: @McNets yes then it is Globally .

Comment: Duplicated means two sequential positive values for the same day? Could it happens between two different days?

Comment: Duplicated means two sequential positive/negative values for any day.yes it can happen between any other day

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query (assuming table name as tbl):

**Logic : if it is reversed then it will have one positive and one negative value in your case 100 and -100 so sum of them will be zero hence in having clause we are ignoring them .**

```
select count(Id),name,amount from tbl group by name,day,amount  having count(id)>1  and sum(amount)>0
```